# Youtube embed and PHP displaying iframe but with display error

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, iframe, youtube

I am using a theme called gridby for wordpress that uses its own plugin to change the featured image to an iframe of vimeo or youtube when the fb_video field contains a link in the post editor and displays the video image in the blog feed page and the iframe in the post instead of featured image. I only used it for a vimeo link so far which works fine and today just tried to put in a youtube video link with /embed at the end and without and still showing error. Its not my code so don't want to brake it further if someone can help me be great as I need this functionality. I put the iframe into a blank post in the editor and that displays fine just not displaying through the PHP code.

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
 *  Video Functions
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

/*  display url image big youtube and vimeo
/* ------------------------------------ */

if ( !function_exists('video_image') ) {

    function video_image($url, $size){ 

        $image_url = parse_url($url);

        if($size == 'small') {

            if($image_url['host'] == 'www.youtube.com' || $image_url['host'] == 'youtube.com'){
                $array = explode("&", $image_url['query']);
                return "http://img.youtube.com/vi/".substr($array[0], 2)."/1.jpg";

            } else if($image_url['host'] == 'www.vimeo.com' || $image_url['host'] == 'vimeo.com'){
                $hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/".substr($image_url['path'], 1).".php"));
                return $hash[0]["thumbnail_small"];
            }

        } else if($size == 'hd') {

            if($image_url['host'] == 'www.youtube.com' || $image_url['host'] == 'youtube.com'){
                $array = explode("&", $image_url['query']);
                return "http://img.youtube.com/vi/".substr($array[0], 2)."/hqdefault.jpg";

            } else if($image_url['host'] == 'www.vimeo.com' || $image_url['host'] == 'vimeo.com'){
                $hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/".substr($image_url['path'], 1).".php"));
                return $hash[0]["thumbnail_large"];
            }
        }

    }

}

/*  display iframe of youtube and vimeo
/* ------------------------------------ */

if ( !function_exists('video_player') ) {

    function video_player($url, $autoplay){ 

        $image_url = parse_url($url);

        if($autoplay == '1') {

            if($image_url['host'] == 'www.youtube.com' || $image_url['host'] == 'youtube.com'){
                $array = explode("&", $image_url['query']);
                return "<iframe title='YouTube video player' width='400' height='275' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/".substr($array[0], 2)."?wmode=trasparent&autoplay=1' frameborder='0' wmode='opaque' allowfullscreen></iframe>";

            } else if($image_url['host'] == 'www.vimeo.com' || $image_url['host'] == 'vimeo.com'){

                return "<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/".substr($image_url['path'], 1)."?autoplay=true' width='400' height='275' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen'></iframe>";
            }

        } else {

            if($image_url['host'] == 'www.youtube.com' || $image_url['host'] == 'youtube.com'){
                $array = explode("&", $image_url['query']);
                return "<iframe title='YouTube video player' width='400' height='275' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/".substr($array[0], 2)."?wmode=trasparent' frameborder='0' wmode='opaque' allowfullscreen></iframe>";

            } else if($image_url['host'] == 'www.vimeo.com' || $image_url['host'] == 'vimeo.com'){

                return "<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/".substr($image_url['path'], 1)."' width='400' height='275' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen'></iframe>";
            }

        }

    }

}


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
 *  Filter Thumbnail
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'post_thumbnail_html', 10, 3 );

    function post_thumbnail_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id) { 

        $video = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'fb_video', true );

        if ($html) { /* If have thumbnail image set */

            if ($video != '') {

                if (is_single()){ /* Show playe on single page */

                    if( function_exists('video_player')) { 

                    ?>

                        <div class='video-container'><?php echo video_player($video, 0); ?></div>

                    <?php 

                    }

                } else { 

                    echo '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-4x"></i>'. $html;

                }

            } else {

                echo $html;

            }

        } else { /* If haven't thumbnail image set */

            if ($video != '') {

                if (is_single()){ /* Show playe on single page */

                    if( function_exists('video_player')) { 

                    ?>

                        <div class='video-container'><?php echo video_player($video, 0); ?></div>

                    <?php 

                    }

                } else { 

                    echo '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-4x"></i><img class="img-res" src="'. video_image($video, 'hd').'" alt="' . esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) ) . '" />';

                }

            } 

        }

    }



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

had to use the /watch?v= version of the url to get it to appear. Question I have though in relation to this would it not of been easier to just ask user to input the id for youtube into a custom field? that way you could just put the iframe in to the page template and use the get meta function to insert it after the / ?

Thats how I would input the video itself but how would I go about getting the image of the video that way for the blog page posts? Dont see the need for a plugin really I want to use this functionality in my own theme so looking for a cleaner alternative

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/optimise-youtube-video-embed/

This Plugin may help you to solve the iframe problem. This will increase the page load by dynamically. Once your button is clicked only your video will be embedded.

Include the shortcode in your page or post.You can add your custom image as video banner.

```
[eh_optimize_youtube_embed video="youtube_link" banner="banner_image_link_optional"]
```